# Storing type as a dictionary key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a mapping `GenericInterface -> ConcreteFactory<GenericInterface>` in typescript. And it works as long as `GenericInterace` has no methods or properties. But if I'm adding something to this interface, than this error occurs: `Property 'XXX' is missing in type 'typeof ClassThatImplementsGenericInterface' but required in type 'GenericInterface'`.

I assume that this happens because `getOrCreate` expects instance and not a type, but i don't understand how I can implement such behaviour in typescript without using strings (component names) as dictionary keys.

```js
// how factories are stored
private _factories: Dictionary<IComponent, Factory<IComponent>>;

// creates and returns factory for component
public getOrCreate<T extends IComponent>(component: IComponent): Factory<T> {
   if (this._factories.has(component)) {
      return this._factories.get(component) as Factory<T>;
   }

   let factory = new Factory<T>();

   this._factories.set(component, factory);

   return factory as Factory<T>;
}

// without XXX everything works
interface IComponent {
    XXX(): string;
}

// this is where error occurs
factories.getOrCreate(TestComponent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dictionary<IComponent` bit literally says, that your key **is** IComponent. However, this is not what you are trying to do: the key should rather be *something that creates* `IComponent`.

Take a look at how the official documentation describes using [constructors in interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).

Let's create another interface for that:

```
interface IComponentCtor {
    new (): IComponent;
}
```

This describes something that creates IComponent (add constructor parameters as needed).

```
class TestComponent implements IComponent {
    constructor() {} // complies with IComponentCtor
}
```

And the signature of getOrCreate is now

```
public getOrCreate(component: IComponentCtor): Factory<IComponent>
```

Now you can use TestComponent as a key of your dictionary as IComponentCtor: `Dictionary<IComponentCtor, Factory<IComponent>>`.